# How to install custom tabs for facebook pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tabs

I have created some custom tabs for facebook pages, like when the user clicks on the add custom tabs, im fetching the user pages but how can i make them to install the custom tab to the particular page on which he clicks.

```
li.innerHTML = "Name: <a href='http://facebook.com/"+page.id+"'>"+page.name+"</a>";
```

From the above code, i could get only the list of user pages, among them when the user clicks on a particular page (i.e.,page1), it should direct them to their page1 profile by adding the custom tab. How can i make them to install the custom tabs?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `manage_pages` permission from the user, you can add your app to their page via the API - see here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

There's no other way to automate it, and using static links are you're suggesting above is prone to break if the Facebook web interface ever changes.

Comment: im having the manage_pages permission for the users....But how to make the users to make add my custom tab with this link in php..
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=APP_ID&method=POST
  &access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN